# Gnu screen : load multiple configuration files

Tags: gnu-screen

Is it possible to load multiple configuration files in Gnu screen?

I tried multiple `-c` options, in vain.

The basic idea is to keep my default `~/.screenrc` loaded, and add a custom session configuration above it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What I do is that I have a common screenrc file and I include it from custom session files. For example I have `~/.config/screen/gnus.screenrc` containing

```
sessionname gnus
source common.screenrc
chdir /

screen -t gnus emacs -nw -f gnus
```

And I run `scr gnus` to open this session, where `scr` is a script that arranges to either attach to a running session or open a new session with the specified name, and uses the session name to construct the path to the configuration file.

```
#!/bin/sh
session_name=$1
rc_file=~/.config/screen/$session_name.screenrc
exec screen -c "$rc_file" -S "$session_name" -r -R -d "$@"
```